# align heading text with subsequent text on the same line

Tags: html, css

I'm tyring to put an 'edit' link on the same line as a heading, off the right of the page and the link text aligned with the bottom of the heading text. I want something like:

[want](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxiscONrgQ2DNThlM2U3NjktOGFjMS00ODUzLWFhM2QtYjM1YTBiNmM4ZTY5)

My first attempt was:

```
<div>
  <div style="float: left; width:600px;background-color: red">
     <h1>Something</h1>
  </div>
  <div style="float: left; background-color: yellow ">
    <a href=#>Edit</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

but that gave me:

[got](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxiscONrgQ2DNThlM2U3NjktOGFjMS00ODUzLWFhM2QtYjM1YTBiNmM4ZTY5)

I've tried quite a few things to get the 'Edit' to be aligned along the bottom with the 'Something', but none seem to work.

Has anyone got any suggestions? Is wrapping everything in divs like this the wrong way to go about it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit - arghh, sorry I mixed the two images the wrong way round. The text was correct though, I want the link text to be bottom aligned with the heading text. Fixed now.

### Update

Thanks to those who made suggestions and comments.

I've come up with with a few more possibilities (although I realise in stepping back and asking if there's a better approach, in some options I've consequently relaxed the original spec somewhat):

Solution 1: similar to chipcullen's suggestion, but set width in outer div. This has the advantage of bringing the link to within the 600px width:

```
  <div style="position: relative; width: 600px">
    <h1>Solution 1</h1>
    <a style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;href="#">Edit</a>
  </div><br/>
```

Solution 2: as with (1) but, but use my own class rather than H1, and allow the link          to float right. This has the advantage (?) of not having to use position: absolute, but you still 
         need to set margin-top.

```
 <div style="width: 600px">
   <span class="myHeader">Solution 2</span>
   <a style="float: right; margin-top:14px;" href="#">Edit</a>
 </div><br/>
```

Solution 3: as with (2) but use h1 and override the display attribute. Has the advantage of making using of other attributes defined elsewhere on h1:

```
 <div style="width: 600px">
   <h1 style="display:inline;">Solution 3</h1>
   <a style="float: right; margin-top:14px;" href="#">Edit</a>
 </div><br/>
```

Solution 4: nest the link element in the h1, and style the link, in this case by specifying a
          Twitter Bootstrap button:

```
 <div style="width: 600px">
  <h1>Solution 4
      <a class="btn" style="margin-top:4px;float: right;" href="#">Edit</a>
  </h1>
 </div>
```

They all seem to work, has anyone got any thoughts on which is preferable? Solutions 2 - 4 I guess are a bit more fragile as the hard-wired margin-top setting depends on the h1 line height, but at the same time they feel a bit more concise to me.

Comment: In which browser do you get this behaviour?

Comment: @bazmegakapa - sorry only just seen your question. In Chrome and Firefox, not test any others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't need the all of the div's. If you really want to get this to behave, you could always use position: absolute;

Markup:

```
<header>
   <h1>Something</h1>
   <a class="edit_link" href="#">Edit</a>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  width: 600px;
 }

.edit_link {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
 }
```

I'm not saying it's the only right way, but **a** way.

Comment: btw - holding off marking the question as answered for a moment - curious to see if there are any solutions that don't use 'position: absolute'.

Comment: @DamianH What's your problem with `position: absolute;`?

Comment: @bazmegakapa - hmm, I'm not sure, but using 'position: absolute', feels a bit of a kludge to me. Intuitively there feels like there ought to be a more 'flow friendly' way. I have to admit to not being massively experienced with HTML, so I'm happy to hear that this is best practice. What do you think?

Comment: @DamianH There is no problem with taking something out of the flow. You are encouraged to do so. It is just the same as with anything else: if you know what you're doing, do it. `position: absolute` is a pretty standard property and you should use it. It adds a very useful tool to your kit. Combined with a `relative` parent it is almost magic.

Comment: The only reason I suggested "position:absolute" is because the OP was/is having issues getting an "edit" link to show up exactly where they wanted. Sometimes it's just not worth getting the 'flow' to behave like you want. Also, as this is an "edit" link, I'm going to make a guess this is a link meant for logged in users of a system, not all visitors. I also try to avoid "position:absolute", but if it's for kind of a solitary element like this, I think it's fine. Trying to achieve an entire layout this way is not the best way for sure.

Comment: @chipcullen Your solution is fine. There is no reason to avoid this property. In certain situations, you can even create a layout that is mostly based on `position`. The "flow" serves you, not vice versa. Btw, forgot to upvote your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this css to the edit float

```
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
border:0px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer - doesn't seem to make a difference, though.

Comment: create a mockup code at [jsfidde.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) make sure you hit the save button before sharing with us.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use **two** classes for your `<div>` tag. such as `#header` and `#header-right`. It's what I usually use.

Example:

```
#header {
  width: 98%;
  min-width: 750px;
  height : 45px;
  margin : 0 auto;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-bottom : 4px;
  color : #ffffff;
  background: #999999; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

#header-right {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  float: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
  <h1 ><a href="http://mysite.com">MySite.com</a></h1>
  <p>A site for me. Not you.</p>
  <div id="header-right">
    <p>Because who wants to share a website...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div>Edit</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header *{
    display: inline-block;
}

.header {
    text-align: left;
}
```

You could also set widths etc.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler way of doing it is:

```
<div>
    <a style="float:right; clear:left" href=#>Edit</a>
    <h1>Something</h1>
</div>
```

[image]

Be sure to put the heading after the link, so the link doesn't disappear into the html below that.